# How do I setup a Linux based kiosk?

Tags: linux

I'm currently looking into building a kiosk running linux. Here's what I need it to do:

Run Apache, PHP, and MySQL

Launch a web browser in full screen mode (loads local content hosted by Apache)
Auto-login to 'kiosk' user

If they need to configure wireless/wired, they can use a key command to quit the web browser, launch the wireless/wired config, and then relaunch the full screen browser. However, I don't want them to have any user folders (if possible) or the ability to save things other than network settings.

Restricts any key commands to perform any other tasks
Provides an on-screen keyboard to enter text
Read-only system, except for a partition to store data (user sessions)
Ability to add/remove printers (admin only)
Ability to connect to wired and wireless connections (any user)
Play flash files and other common web media content (including audio)

How do I set this up?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Ooops! How do I set this up?

Comment: I know how to install apache/php/mysql  Just not sure if I should use X11 or KDE. And how to setup autologin to launch lets say Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

xguest in combination with [SELINUX](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Confining_Users-xguest_Kiosk_Mode.html) will provide you with this functionality.